# Having trouble getting id from while loop to query

Tags: php

I have a bunch of items I list on a page and each of these items have an id associated with them on there link.

For instance, when you hover over the items you get a url of items.php?id=5.

I have my while loop which produces all of the items on this page including the links, how do I carryover that ID into my other code?

Here is my code that brings up all the items.

```
while ($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo 
        "<li>
            <img style='width: 200px; height: 200px' src='images/inventory/" . $results['Image'] . "'/>" . 
            "<div class='infoContainer'>" .
            "<a class='productLink' href='selectItems.php?status=active&id=" . $results['ID'] . "'>" . $results['ProductName'] . "</a>" . 
            "<br />" . 
            "<i>Currently Available </i>" . 
            "<i class='quantity'>" . $results['Quantity'] . "</i>" . 
            "</div>" .
        "</li>";
    }
```

Now I simply want to put each items attributes into a dialog box. How do I carryover an id from above to get the right data back?

```
    <div id="dialog" title="A title">
        <?php

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` = ";
            $query = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
            var_dump($sql);

            $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

            var_dump($results);
        ?>


    </div>
```

Comment: Better use ajax to get it done.

Comment: I thought about going that route. Just wanted to see if there was something I was missing maybe.

Comment: While your in the loop create a hidden dialog div with the contents, so when you *do what needs to be done* reference the id of that div

Comment: just use JQuery-Ajax or Simply Ajax to load data from another .php and then bind mouse over the links to show a div whose html() will be the data returned by Ajax

Comment: You should simply construct a string, append the data to it, and load it into dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call a javascript function and send id in it.. 
donot forget to include the jquery files.. 
this method loads the data using AJAX..

```
<script>
function getData(idtosend){
    $.post('getdata.php', id: idtosend, function (response){
         $("#dialog").html(response);
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is the code of getdata.php file:

```
<?php
//Connect mysql here
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` = $id";
$query = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
var_dump($sql);
$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
var_dump($results);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me piece it together.

Answer (score 0):

in PHP you cat use ob_start() -  this is output buffer for echo operations.

after save result in variable or array and put it into needful block on page